# How do I decouple a parallel pings processing system

Tags: database-design, architecture

I have a system which recieves 1000s of GPS pings every second which are stored in a RDBMS table, lets call it the pingsTable. These pings are then read from the database and are processed individually in multiple processors to extract valuable information for the end user. 
As of now, our system maintains a column in the pingsTable itself namely processed_state which basically specifies if a ping has been processed through a particular processor or not. For example, processed state 3 means that the pings is processed by the first 3 processors. Every processor is configured to read pings having processed state lesser than its own state and update the processed_state to its own state once the ping is processed.
The problem is that even though these processors do not depend on each other, I am still forced to process pings in a defined order.

My intention is to decouple these processors from each other so that I can run these processors parallely. Also, I need to maintain the processed_state of each ping because I may need to query already processed pings while analysing these pings.

I can think of maintaining a separate table for each processor and do a join to check if a ping is processed or not. I am looking for a more efficient and extendable design for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to process pings in parallel. Processing has to go via all independent processors ( services). While maintaining in DB the processors which have done processing

The easiest way to do is

Assign ID to your processor. ID should based on bitwise operator ( i.e. 1,2,4,8,16 .etc.).

1. Feed ping to all processor
2. When server is done processing update DB with (processor ID + any existing value)
   Use bitwise operation in your SQL queries

For example 1 ping needs to be processed by 5 processors

- Processor 5 process ping update DB value 16
- processor 2 process ping update DB value 16 + 2 = 18
- processor 3 process ping update DB value 18 + 4 = 22

Now you want to query that processor 4 processed the ping. In your SQL's where clause use "bitwise and" for operator 8

This way you don't need separate table etc.. And things without join make it faster. On negative side you have to take care of DB update, row locking if two processors are trying to update same value.